# Oracle Sql - I have two tables and need to filter table1 with results from table2. I need to return all of table1 if table2 is empty

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I'm currently turning a comma-separated string into a number table with the field name of ID. I'm then trying to do an nvl to select all if the generated table is null.

```
table1.ID = NVL(table2.ID, table1.ID)
```

I have two tables and need to filter table1 with results from table2. I need to return all of table1 if table2 is empty.

Scenario I

Table1

```
ID    
1    
2    
3    
4
```

Table2 (Empty)

```
ID

Return rows 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Scenario II

Table1

```
ID    
1    
2    
3    
4
```

Table2

```
ID    
2
3
```

Return rows 2, 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use filtering in the `where` clause:

```
select t1.id
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table2) or
      exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id);
```

I don't think `join` is the right way to express this logic.

Comment: If I can populate an empty row in table2 and do the join with NVL would that be more efficient than this? I have around 1 million records in table 1.

Comment: @Matt . . . This is probably the most efficient solution.  I am guessing you already have indexes on the `id`s which is what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `UNION`

```
select t1.id
from table1 t1 
where not exists (select 1 from table2 where id = t1.id) union all
select t2.id
from table2 t2
where exist (select 1 from table1 where id = t2.id);
```